# php chmod mkdir

Tags: chmod, mkdir

I want to know what is the safiest chmode for creating user folders and user files. I create a user folder for each registration (in mode 700) and users can upload images into their folder. I read the php documentation but I'm still confuse about terms "owner", "group", "public"? Can I have a full explanation about it? (I can't found a good explanation on google)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This description seems decent:

http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml